# Looping through hibernate data source issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I have implemented HibernateLoopDataSource in which I have constructor, one without applied criteria and one with. It looks like following

```
HibernateLoopDataSource.java

//code trimmed
HibernateLoopDataSource(Session hibernate, Class<?> typeOfClass){
  this.hibernate = hibernate;
  this.typeOfClass = typeOfClass;
}

HibernateLoopDataSource(Session hibernate, Class<?> typeOfClass, AppliedCriteria appliedCriteria){
  this.hibernate = hibernate;
  this.typeOfClass = typeOfClass;

}



AppliedCriteria.java //looks like following
```

it is an interface and contains only one method

```
applyingCriteria(Criteria criteria);
```

and

```
GettingArticles.java

// code trimmed

public LoopDataSource getArticles(){
return new HibernateLoopDataSource(hibernate, Article.class, new AppliedCriteria(){
 public void applyingCriteria(Criteria criteria){
   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("article.id", fullCommentPageListing.getArticle().getId()));}});}
```

However, when I try to initialize it doesn't report anything, however it loops without applying criteria. What may be the cause of this issue, I am stuck on it 2 hours, it may be some trivial, and I can't see it, 'cause I am working on this for 8 hours. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do anything with the criteria argument in the constructor:

```
HibernateLoopDataSource(Session hibernate, 
                        Class<?> typeOfClass, 
                        AppliedCriteria appliedCriteria){
    this.hibernate = hibernate;
    this.typeOfClass = typeOfClass;
    // you should have this.appliedCriteria = appliedCriteria here
}
```

Comment: Yeah, probably a mistake from copy-pasting. Will check it now, if it works.

Comment: Just checked, nothing happens. Will have to look for Tomcat logs.

Comment: We don't know what a HibernateLoopDataSource might be. It's impossible to find a bug in some code without seeing the code.

Comment: I have just solved this by implementing additionalConstraintCallback bounding to the prepare() function. You couldn't call it anyway, 'cause it wasn't configured there. :)